# Partitioning a hard disk (UEFI)

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, 15.10

On my laptop, there is a UEFI BIOS and hard disk 750 GB.
Tell me please:
some partition table should be used when partitioning the hard drive and better his mark (Well, in the sense of how to partition).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The installer will partition the drive for you.  If you have a more specific question you will need to edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, "UEFI firmware" is more accurate than "UEFI BIOS".

I don't really understand your question. If you are asking about how to partition a drive, look into sgdisk. It's like sfdisk, but it handles GPT tables instead of the traditional MBR partition tables used in the past. GPT is what UEFI firmware is capable of reading.

Comment: Well, in the sense of how to partition

Comment: "How to partition" is an *extremely* open-ended question. You may want to check the [`cgdisk` Walkthrough](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/cgdisk-walkthrough.html) page of the GPT fdisk documentation, then come back with a clarified question. (Given your question, `cgdisk` is almost certainly a better choice than the `sgdisk` that Warren suggested. [GParted](http://gparted.org/) can be even easier to use in most respects.)

Comment: GParted and `cgdisk` are better for interactive use, and `sgdisk` is better for scripted use.